# What's the difference the Triple Scalar Product volume formula and a similar formula?

Tags: vectors, volume

The formula to calculate the volume of a parallelpiped is:

> $$V = u \cdot (v × w)$$

But what's the difference between that formula and

> $$V = u × (v \cdot w)$$

Comment: The latter is not defined. The scalar product $v\cdot w$ is a scalar (d'uh), so you cannot form a cross product with it and a vector. If, instead, you intended to write that $V=(u\times v)\cdot w$, then that formula also works, and there is no difference. It is not unlike the formulas for the area of a triangle. You can pick any of the three sides as a base, and the correct area comes out if you use the corresponding height. Here the choice of two vectors in the cross product amounts to selecting one of the faces as a base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second formula cannot be right because it does not even make sense mathematically: The scalar product $v \cdot w$ produces a number. This means that $u \times (v \cdot w)$ cannot be computed. The cross product is only defined between two vectors!